# shaderlight: All my images are rendering black. How to fix?

Tags: animation, model, rendering, sketchup

I am using sketch up pro to create a model, and just downloaded shader light for rendering the scenes, yesterday it was working fine. and today, rendering is just showing black images, tried many times but getting same output. please help.

Comment: just got the solution for this issue. the time that was set in the shadow setting was 
UTC+12:00 , that why the images were rendering black. just changed  it to UTC-07:00. working fine for me now.